# Elasticsearch - get docs with array field size greater than 1

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get all docs with a field, which is an array, with size greater than 1.
I'm using the following command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XGET '127.0.0.1:9200/poly/_search?pretty' -d '
{ "query": { "bool": { "filter": { "script" : { "script" : "doc['emoji'].length > 1" } } } } }
'
```

but I get the following error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "compile error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "doc[emoji].length > 1",
          "    ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "doc[emoji].length > 1",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "position" : {
          "offset" : 4,
          "start" : 0,
          "end" : 21
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "poly",
        "node" : "Dnp4BI4YSgCz-C-p8NmcTg",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "query_shard_exception",
          "reason" : "failed to create query: compile error",
          "index_uuid" : "HlWRuJb5TY-L_2_9iyuVmg",
          "index" : "poly",
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "script_exception",
            "reason" : "compile error",
            "script_stack" : [
              "doc[emoji].length > 1",
              "    ^---- HERE"
            ],
            "script" : "doc[emoji].length > 1",
            "lang" : "painless",
            "position" : {
              "offset" : 4,
              "start" : 0,
              "end" : 21
            },
            "caused_by" : {
              "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason" : "cannot resolve symbol [emoji]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "script_exception",
      "reason" : "compile error",
      "script_stack" : [
        "doc[emoji].length > 1",
        "    ^---- HERE"
      ],
      "script" : "doc[emoji].length > 1",
      "lang" : "painless",
      "position" : {
        "offset" : 4,
        "start" : 0,
        "end" : 21
      },
      "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "cannot resolve symbol [emoji]"
      }
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Nevertheless, the field "emoji" exists in my ElasticSearch docs, as you can see in the result to the following command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XGET '127.0.0.1:9200/poly/_search?pretty' -d '
{
   "_source": ["emoji"],
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
            "exists" : {
               "field" : "emoji"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Here is the result for the previous command:

```
  "took" : 28,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "poly",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1307256887860174848",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "emoji" : [
            "❤️"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "poly",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1278766523134414848",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "emoji" : [
            "⏩"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "poly",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1298632385605431296",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "emoji" : [
            "\uD83D\uDC47\uD83C\uDFFF",
            "\uD83D\uDC47\uD83C\uDFFF",
            "\uD83D\uDC47\uD83C\uDFFF",
            "\uD83D\uDC47\uD83C\uDFFF"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "poly",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1300563120184651776",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "emoji" : [
            "\uD83D\uDC4D",
            "\uD83D\uDE00",
            "\uD83D\uDE80"
          ]
        }
      },
     ]
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me why I'm getting that error above?

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: When running your query on ES 7.x I get the last document ok, which is correct since all others have only a unique emoji (the third one has 4x the same emoji, which only gets indexed once). Can you share your mapping with `GET poly`, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip characters in your command check command below:

**Script:**

```
"script": {"script": "doc['\''emoji'\''].length > 1"
```

**Command:**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XGET '127.0.0.1:9200/poly/_search?pretty' -d '{  "query": {"bool": {"filter": {"script": {"script": "doc['\''emoji'\''].length > 1"}}}}}'
```